# DHCP Server not reachable from Access Point

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, pihole

My Network Setup consist of two Routers, one LTE Router (Router 1) working as a Gateway to the Internet, the other one (Router 2) working as Access Point in order to expand the network accessibility.

In addition, a RPi Zero running Pi.Hole acts as the DHCP Server of the Network.

**Problem:**

Within my network Setup, devices that connect via Router 2 don't get the correct IP assigned by the DHCP Server (DHCP Range: 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.250) but end up with 169.....s . 
Devices that connect via Router 1 get corrects IPs.

This Problem started when I introduced Pi.Hole as DHCP Server. Before that, Router 1 was acting as DHCP Server and every device got a correct IP.
I can reach devices with wrong IPs via ssh and those devices even use Pi.Hole as Ad-Sinkhole but fail to communicate with its DHCP Server.

I'd appreciate every hint on why this is not working and if there's a possibility to get this to work.

**Setup:**

**Router 1:**

- Model: Huawei E5186s-22a.
- Firmware: 21.306.01.07.22 (Standard Huawei Firmware)
- IP: 192.168.1.1
- DHCP is deactivated.
- This Router establishes the connection to the internet.

**Router 2:**

- Model: Linksys WRT54GS Version 6
- Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r40559 micro (08/06/19)
- IP: 192.168.1.2
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- Local DNS: 192.168.1.1
- DHCP is deactivated.
- This router works as AP and has been configured according to this [Guide](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point#Normal_Version_.28Same_Subnet.29) (Normal Version (Same Subnet))

Router 1 and Router 2 share one Wireless SSID but work on different channels.

**DHCP Server:**

- Model: RPi Zero with PiHole installed
- IP: 192.168.1.10
- DHCP enabled:
- DHCP Range: 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.250

**Wiring:**

- There's a wired ethernet connection between Router 1 and Router 2.
- There's a wired ethernet connection between Router 1 and the DHCP Server.
- The DHCP Server connects to LAN 1 of Router 1.
- LAN 2 of Router 1 connects to LAN 1 of Router 2.

**Attempts so far:**

- Activating DHCP forwarding from the Router 2 to the DHCP Server --> No visible effect.
- Setting the DHCP (192.168.1.10) server as local DNS on Router 2  -->
  Router 2 shows  in the Pi.Hole's Log as Device . Beside that nothing changed.
- Plugging the DHCP Server into the Router 2 --> Problem stays but now device connected to Router 1 end up with a wrong IP. Devices connected to the Router 2 get the correct IPs.
- Connecting LAN 2 on Router 1 to the Internet Port on Router 2 but that did not change anything apparent.
- I tried changing the wiring so that the DHCP connects to LAN 2 of Router 1 and LAN 1 of Router 1 connects to LAN 1 of Router 2. --> again no change

I`ve been running wireshark to look for DHCP requests.

Here's a device that ended up with a wrong IP trying to get something from the DHCP Server:

```
Number  Time         Source     Destination      Protocol  Length  Info
1108    133.580324   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.255  DHCP      378    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x47de264f
1079    115.557997   0.0.0.0    255.255.255.255  DHCP      392    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x46df78a0
```

I could not find any other log from this device with another DHCP message than DHCP Discover.

Comment: Does the RPi receive DHCP "discover" packets from clients? Does it send out offers in response? And does it receive the actual "requests" after that?

Comment: Yes, Devices that connect via Router 1 get corrects IPs --> I just realised that I failed to mention this in my post and added this.

Comment: Right, but I'm specifically asking about the devices which _don't_ work...

Comment: OK I did not get that. I'm not quite sure how I can monitore that but it seems like a good idea to get into that. Any advice on a monitoring tool?

Comment: I added two lines from a wireshark log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
It turned out Router 1 has a LAN/WAN Port. As soon as I plugged Pi.Hole into that Port, everything started working.

Working wiring:
Pi.Hole connects to Router 1 on the LAN/WAN Port via ethernet cable.
Router 1 LAN 1 connects to Router 2 LAN 1 via ethernet cable.